# Important details about exchange trade fund?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, etf

I am a non-expert who's thinking of putting his money into stocks, and ETFs look like an attractive option. What are some important things I should know about ETFs before buying into any?

Comment: You should always read the ETF prospectus before buying. It tells you exactly what you are buying.

Comment: Have you looked at some posts tagged [etf](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etf) on this site?

Comment: [What to Look for in ETF](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/74475/what-to-look-for-in-etf?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

1. Diversification. Based on your intended asset allocation, you will want to spread your money in many different types of stocks to reduce risk. You should research what types a given ETF holds -- country (US vs. international), size of company (large-cap vs. small-cap), etc. Note, you referred to stocks, but there are also ETFs for bonds, commodities, etc.
2. Fees. Most ETFs are passively managed index funds and many have very low management fees, a small fraction of a percent per year (and they can be bought for low or no commission using discount brokers). Management expenses come out of the value of ETF shares and reduce your returns over time. ETFs that have higher fees tend to be those you wouldn't want anyway: Small/niche sector ETFs (with fewer assets to support fixed expenses), those holding illiquid assets, or those with active management trying to "beat the market".
3. Tax efficiency. If the ETF is held in a taxable account (as opposed to a qualified retirement plan), will you receive taxable distributions that you may not want? ETFs naturally tend to be tax efficient, but you may want to avoid stocks paying large dividends, for example, if you don't need current income.

Comment: Minor comment, but fees are now even lower due to some funds passing along money made from lending out shares. Hence some index funds now have zero or even small negative fees. That is definitely something for a retail investor to seek. You might also mention liquidity -- another non-trivial advantage of many ETFs.

Comment: @kurtosis What are some examples of zero or negative-fee index funds?

Comment: There are a number of zero-fee funds. Fidelity's Zero Total Market Index Fund (FZROX) is one example. Fidelity and BNY Mellon have other zero-feee funds as well. Salt Financial had the first negative-fee fund but apparently they just changed the fee structure since they weren't attracting much in AUM. (MY guess is a Fidelity negative-feee fund would not have such problems.)